# How can you rotate the vertical axis of an HDR loaded into a THREE.js scene?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matrix, three.js, matrix-multiplication

I was able to successfully load an HDR file into my THREE.js scene and set it as the background and environment for lighting. However, I need to rotate the HDR 180 degrees. It's my understanding that in order to achieve this I would need to create a rotational matrix and multiply that by the matrix of the HDR texture. However my attempt to do this is **not** rotating the HDR. I figured, if I can't rotate the HDR then I'll just rotate the whole scene. This also didn't work so it leads me to believe there is a fault in how I'm attempting to rotate the matrix.

```
// ----- Load HDRI Lighting -----
const hdrTextureURL = new URL(hdr, import.meta.url)
const loader = new RGBELoader();
loader.load(hdrTextureURL, function(texture) {
   texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

   //create rotational matrix to multiply texture
   const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), Math.PI);
   texture.matrix.multiply(rotationMatrix);
   texture.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

   scene.background = texture;
   scene.environment = texture;
   scene.environment.rotation
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no dedicated support for this right now. Please read the following issue at GitHub for more information: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16328

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up with this solution after a few hours of unsuccessful research on the internet.

So in essence I have a solar system, where camera should rotate and center on planets every time I click on them, and as you may already know, it's pretty hard to animate the camera, if ever possible, without pulling your hair out.

As a result, to give the illusion that it's in fact the camera rotating, I rotate the whole scene, and to make the background rotate as well, I map it inside a sphere.

This is a React-Three-Fiber code but I think you'll get the idea.

```
<animated.mesh rotation-y={rotation}>
    <sphereGeometry args={[200, 200, 200]} />
    <meshStandardMaterial
      side={THREE.BackSide}
      map={envMap}
    />
  </animated.mesh>
```

You'll have to play with the sphere size and min/max distance of zooming of the camera to make it look right, but other than that, everything should work fine.
This probably is not a good solution in cases where you'd need to have perfect picture with no distortions, but boxGeometry might come to the resuce.